# Что такое тавтология?

Tags: тавтология

На одном сообществе по русскому языку возник спор по поводу тавтологий. Одни утверждали, что тавтологией можно назвать повторение только однокоренных или одинаковых слов - сакраментальное "масло масляное". Но вот, что говорит по поводу тавтологий википедия: "Тавтология (риторика) -  риторическая фигура, представляющая собой повторение одних и тех же или близких по смыслу слов". Заметим: близких по смыслу. То есть, например, "замерзший снег" тоже будет тавтологией? А как быть тогда с омонимами, вроде "заплела косу и взяла косу"?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ПЛЕОНАЗМ И ТАВТОЛОГИЯ](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.23)

ПЛЕОНАЗМ (греч. *излишество*).

Средство лексической выразительности, основанное на использовании в предложении или тексте БЛИЗКИХ ПО ЗНАЧЕНИЮ слов, создающих смысловую избыточность.

1) Плеоназм встречается в фольклоре: жили-были, грусть-тоска. Также это средство широко используется в художественной литературе для усиления эмоций, оценок: *Я страстно хочу, я жажду вашего голоса.*

2) Разновидность лексической ошибки, когда в словосочетании или предложении употребляются излишние со смысловой точки зрения слова: *Они обеспечили ритмичную и бесперебойную работу предприятия.*

3) Типичными примерами ненормативного плеоназма являются словосочетания, в которых значение одного слова повторяет значение другого: *более важнее, первая премьера*.

4) Некоторые плеонастические словосочетания закрепились в языке и не считаются ошибочными, например *спуститься вниз*.

ТАВТОЛОГИЯ (греч. *то же самое* и *слово*) – разновидность плеоназма; употребление ОДНОКРЕННЫХ слов в предложении или тексте.

1) Тавтология встречается в пословицах и поговорках: *Дружба дружбой, а служба службой; битком набит, есть поедом.*

2) Экспрессивно окрашенные тавтологические сочетания характерны для фольклора: *Скоро сказка сказывается, да не скоро дело делается; сиднем сидеть, горе горькое.*

3) Намеренное использование однокоренных слов служит средством лексической выразительности в художественной литературе и публицистике: *Горьким смехом моим посмеюся.*

4) Тавтология представляет собой лексическую ошибку, если употребление однокоренных слов не оправдано стилистическими целями и носит случайный характер: *воедино соединить, станцевать танец*.

Answer (score 2):

тавтология (греч. tautologia из tauto — то же самое + + logos — слово).

1. Тождесловие, повторение сказанного другими словами, не вносящее ничего нового. Авторские слова — это слова автора.
2. Повторение в предложении однокоренных слов. В борьбе за свои права рабочие объединились воедино. Следует отметить следующие особенности произведения. К недостаткам пособия можно отнести недостаточное количество иллюстративного материала.
3. Неоправданная избыточность выражения. Более лучшее положение (в форме лучшее уже заключено значение сравнительной степени). Самые высочайшие вершины (в форме высочайшие уже заключено значение превосходной степени).

Розенталь и др. Словарь лингвистических терминов